# Использование C++ кода в C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net

Народ, подскажите, как использовать `shared_ptr` в C# ?

Есть класс в С++, который имеет метод

```
static std::shared_ptr<DeviceManager> getInstance();
```

Мне необходимо вызвать этот метод, и использовать этот объект из C# приложения.

Пытаюсь реализовать это через C++/CLI враппер.
С++, к сожалению, не знаю :(

Comment: Делать сложные С++ структуры в C# тяжело. Попробуйте проблему решить другим способом

Comment: Попробуйте отредактировать свой вопрос, пояснив, какую именно проблему вы пытаетесь решить таким образом. Возможно существует более подходящее решение, которое вообще не использует C++ http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy

Comment: Среда .NET позволяет выполнять полную сборку мусора, поэтому нет необходимости в контейнере. Может лучше просто хранить ссылки на объекты?